# Web sites login connections

Tags: website, login

Is there any way to see a list with all the active login connections on various web sites from the respective browser?

Edit: for instance if I'm logged in on superuser, stackoverflow, facebook and yahoo, is there a way to see all this in a list?

Comment: Care to elaborate more on what you count as a 'login connection'?

Comment: @Jawa: I think he means "login sessions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible for the browser to know this for certain. In many (most?) cases the "logged in" state information is held at the server (because HTTP is a stateless protocol). For some login mechanisms, the browser has a session cookie for whose value the server keeps track of "logged in" state. You might have clicked a "logout" widget (or been timed out) but your browser could still hold an unexpired session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way for a browser to separate login pages (or logged in pages) from any other regular web pages. So no, there is no way to see such a list.

However, in coming the version of Firefox there is functionality, named as [Account Manager](https://mozillalabs.com/blog/2010/03/account-manager/), that identifies login pages and manages users' web identities. There might as well be some add-ons that are capable of doing this, but none of the plain browsers can do it.